# Creating a class object inside a loop

Tags: ruby, class, iterator

I think my question is pretty simple but I'm not flash on the fundamentals.

I have a class and I want to store data in it from a loop and access those class objects outside of the loop. 
For example, I want code like below

```
class Numbers
  attr_accessor :value

end

n = 1

while n < 10
  p = Numbers.new
  p.value = n
  n += 1
  puts p.value
end
```

but instead of iterating over each Number made inside of the loop, I want to store each class object and iterate over the collection outside of the initial loop. In my mind the code looks like this, but it's clearly not the right way to go about it.

```
class Numbers
  attr_accessor :value
end

n = 1

while n < 10
  Numbers.new
  Numbers.value = n
  n += 1
end

Numbers.each do |f|
  puts f.value
end
```

I ask because I want to apply this technique to a more complex problem, thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: `Numbers.value = n` looks like a mistake. That's calling a method on the class, not on the object instance you just created. You also don't save the thing you create, you just throw it away.

Comment: You really should define `value` inside `initialize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
class Number
  attr_accessor :value
end

numbers = (1..9).map do |n| 
  number = Number.new
  number.value = n
  number
end
```

How does this work?

- `map` is a loop that creates an array with the result from each iteration
- `(1..9).map { |n| ... }` hence creates an array of 9 number objects

I guess you are new to Ruby so here is some help with classes and objects

- `Number` is a class
- `number` is an object
- `Number.new` creates an object that is an instance of class `Number`
- `value` is defined by `Number` class and thus available on instances of that class
- `number.value` is thus valid
- `Number.value` is thus invalid and does not make sense
- Use an array to store many objects

So your text should thus say

*"I have a class and I want to create instances of it from a loop and access these instances outside of the loop. [...] But instead of iterating over each object made inside of the loop, I want to store each instance in an array and iterate over the array outside of the initial loop."*

Comment: I'd argue that `.map` is more powerful and `.inject` is unnecessarily complex in this situation. `Enumerable#map` returns an `Array` when a `block` is given. See the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: I am sorry for previous comments. I had a long day at work and made an inappropriate statement regarding wrong using of map here. It is perfectly valid usage, and indeed `inject` is an overkill here. Let me remove my downvote (had to edit the answer, otherwise could not do it)

Comment: No offense taken. Thank you for this note, that is very much appreciated! All the best and enjoy the rest of your day!

Comment: The OP's code (`while n < 10`) is equivalent to `(1..9).map` or `(1...10).map`

Comment: Good catch, fixed!

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you! .map worked perfectly for my use this evening however I definitely need to make an effort to learn how to use .inject properly.

Answer (score 1):

## Refactoring

Since your `Number` value probably shouldn't be changed, you could just set `value` when you create the `Number` object :

```
class Number
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    @value.to_s
  end
end

numbers = Array.new(10) { |i| Number.new(i) }

puts numbers
# => 
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
```

## Range

If you want Numbers between 1 and 9 :

```
numbers = (1..9).map { |i| Number.new(i) }
```

## puts number

`to_s` method has been defined in order to avoid getting :

```
#<Number:0x00000001363a70>
#<Number:0x00000001363a48>
#<Number:0x00000001363a20>
#<Number:0x000000013639f8>
#<Number:0x000000013639d0>
#<Number:0x000000013639a8>
#<Number:0x00000001363980>
#<Number:0x00000001363958>
#<Number:0x00000001363930>
```

when using `puts`

## Basic arithmetic

For basic arithmetic, you could add this method :

```
def +(other)
  self.class.new(value + other.value)
end
```

to `Number`.

Now you can type :

```
puts Number.new(1) + Number.new(2)
#=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ˙class variable˙ like collector for instances.

```
class Number
  attr_accessor :value
  @@numbers = []

  def initialize(value = nil)
    @value = value
    @@numbers << self
  end

  def self.each
    @@numbers.each do |inst|
      yield inst
    end
  end
end
```

And then use

```
1.upto(9){|n| Number.new(n)}

Number.each{|inst| puts inst.value}
# => 1
# => 2
# => 3
# => 4
# => 5
# => 6
# => 7
# => 8
# => 9
```